# wix 64-bit DLL custom action support?

Tags: wix, 64-bit, windows-installer

I'm trying to build both 32-bit and 64-bit installers using WiX, and part of that requires a DLL that runs during the InstallUISequence to check a value typed in by the user.  I used Visual Studio 2010 and the WiX plugin to generate a DLL template and filled it in. Everything works fine when I built the DLL for 32-bit.  When I build it for 64-bit, there are complaints about missing symbols WcaFinalize and WcaGlobalFinalize.

I've read in various discussions from 3-4 years ago that there first was no build of WiX to support 64-bit custom actions, then there was a special Wix35_x64.msi, then that was withdrawn, with the explanation that 32-bit WiX could build 64-bit installers.

Does WiX 3.5 (or 3.6?) support building 64-bit DLLs for inclusion in 64-bit installers?  If so, where do I find the libraries that include WcaFinalize and WcaGlobalFinalize for 64-bit?

Comment: Doesn't your 32-bit custom action work on 64-bit?

Comment: Ultimately, that's what I ended up doing--using a 32-bit DLL with the 64-bit MSI. Then I hit a 2nd problem (see next question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KMoraz is right--simplest is just to run the custom action at 32-bit.  Since all it's doing is verifying that a file exists under a specified directory, that works fine.